# Do Mac Steam keys work for PC?

Tags: steam

The Bioshock Infinite season pass (Steam key) is on offer at the moment, but only for Mac.

Having already bought the stand-alone game Bioshock Infinite a while ago, if I buy this DLC, will I be able to activate and play the DLC on the PC?

Essentially, what I'm asking is:

> What is the difference (if any) between Mac Steam keys and Windows Steam keys?

Comment: When I go to the store page (on my iPhone), it lists the Season Pass at $19.99, for SteamPlay, Windows, and Mac. Where do you see `but only for Mac`?

Comment: @AdamV On GreenManGaming. See here: http://www.greenmangaming.com/s/gb/en/pc/games/shooter/bioshock-infinite-season-pass-mac/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to activate and play the DLC on your PC.

As long as the game supports [Steam Play](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308) there is no difference between Mac / Windows / Linux keys.

I don't know of any multi-platform games on Steam that don't support Steam Play. However, always check before you buy.